# Why does codingbat.com shows 'Error:list index out of range' for prob. List-2>sum67 while my code runs fine locally?

Tags: python

Why does codingbat.com shows 'Error:list index out of range' for prob. List-2>sum67 while my code runs fine locally?

Below is the code that i am trying so far:

```
def sum67(nums):
    s=sum(nums)
    toS=0
    list=[]
    if len(nums)==0:
        return s
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i]==6:
            if len(list)==0:
                list.append(i)
            elif list[-1]==7:
                list.append(i)
        if nums[i]==7 and nums[list[-1]]==6:
            list.append(i)
    if len(list)!=0:
        for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
            if i==len(list)-2:
                toS+=sum(nums[list[i]:list[-1]+1])  
            else:
                toS+=sum(nums[list[i]:list[i+2]])
    return (s-toS)
```

Comment: Your code needs to properly formatted

Comment: I think codingbat is using a different set of data input.
You have the bug locally, but your data set does not show it.

Comment: there is a built in list, and it is not a good idea to name a list just list.

Comment: The bug is in your code, and is triggered by the second set of test values given on codingbat (`[1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7]`)

Comment: By the way your solution is really uselessly complex... you may want to read the doc for `list.index()`. The problem can be solved in exactly 3 (three) lines of (readable) code.

Comment: def sum67(nums):
    sum = 0;
    flag = False;
    for i in range(0, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == 6:
            flag = True;
            continue;
        if flag is True and nums[i] == 7:
            flag = False;
            continue;
        if flag is False:
            sum = sum + nums[i];
    return sum;

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for i in range(0, len(li), 2):
```

to

```
for i in range(0, len(li) -1, 2)
```